# XGBoost with GPU on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, gpu, xgboost, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use XGBoost with GPU on Google Colaboratory. Here is my notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import xgboost as xgb

train_X = np.random.rand(100,5)
train_Y = np.random.choice(2, 100)

test_X = np.random.rand(10,5)
test_Y = np.random.choice(2, 10)

xg_train = xgb.DMatrix(train_X, label=train_Y)
xg_test = xgb.DMatrix(test_X, label=test_Y)

param = {}
# use softmax multi-class classification
param['objective'] = 'multi:softmax'
# scale weight of positive examples
param['eta'] = 0.1
param['max_depth'] = 6
param['silent'] = 1
param['nthread'] = 4
param['num_class'] = 2

param['gpu_id'] = 0
param['max_bin'] = 16
param['tree_method'] = 'gpu_hist'


# watchlist allows us to monitor the evaluation result on all data in the list 
watchlist = [(xg_train, 'train'), (xg_test, 'test')]
num_round = 5

bst = xgb.train(param, xg_train, num_round, watchlist)
```

When I run last line:

```
bst = xgb.train(param, xg_train, num_round, watchlist)
```

I get "Runtime died, Automatically restarting"

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: The code provided by OP here successfully runs for me on Colab (February 22, 2021).

Answer (score 5):

I have got XGBoost running on Colab with GPU support. Download the Linux version from [here](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-wheels/list.html), and then

```
!pip uninstall xgboost
!pip install xgboost-0.81-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

...is working for me.

Comment: This isn't working for me and when I try to update the wheel name from https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/1.2.0/#files
  it doesn't work either.

Comment: it's an issue with pip, just use `!pip install xgboost`

Answer (score 4):

Matt Wehman answer works for me. I had some doubts on how to actually place the file xgboost-0.81-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl inside Colab after download.

The steps are:

1. Download the XGBoost file from the link provided by Matt onto your local machine
2. Upload the file onto the Colab server. this can be done either directly from your computer, or saving to your Google Drive and importing from Drive into Colab. You will need to upload the file each time you start the Colab session (which resets after some time of non-use) and loading from Drive is much faster than from your PC.

   To upload using your PC:

   ```
   from google.colab import files
   files.upload()
   ```

   To upload from Google Drive I install and use pyDrive. The process is described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/use-pydrive-to-upload-files-to-google-drive-folder/26644#26644)
3. Once the XGBoost file is in the Colab local directory, you can finally run the code

```
!pip uninstall xgboost
!pip install xgboost-0.81-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: !wget https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-wheels/xgboost-0.81-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

Comment: List of wheels is here now, from their docs: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/list.html

Answer (score 4):

At the moment it looks like `!pip install -U xgboost` works - seems like the version of xgboost installed on colab was old (0.9.0 or something). The xgboost [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html) also have a link to the [nightly builds](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/list.html) for xgboost which can be installed like `!pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/xgboost-1.4.0_SNAPSHOT%2B4224c08cacceba3f83f90e387c07aa6205a83bfa-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` from a colab jupyter notebook cell. Since it looks like their list of wheels changes sometimes, you might have to search for something like 'xgboost docs wheels' to find the latest location of the wheels if you want to use those.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know we can not import the XGBoost with GPU support on Google Colab, have you checked that?